# This code, no error at building, but error at showing console

Tags: c#

[image: The screen that I met]

```
using System;
namespace A
{
    class program
    {
        public static int FibonacciRecursive(uint number)
        {
            if (number == 0) return 0;
            if (number == 1) return 1;

            return FibonacciRecursive(number - 2) + FibonacciRecursive(number - 1);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FibonacciRecursive(10);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea to solve this obstacle.
Output-window said it suceeded to build.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894969/the-project-doesnt-know-how-to-run-the-profile-consoleapp) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093156/vs2022-the-project-doesnt-know-how-to-run-the-profile) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the project doesn't know how to run the profile ConsoleApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894969/the-project-doesnt-know-how-to-run-the-profile-consoleapp)

Comment: Whatever you do to change your project, you need to call your function in another way, something like `cout >>FibonacciRecursive(10);` or `print(FibonacciRecursive(10));` or something like that (I don't know the exact syntax).